# Are there any 3rd party chatting apps available for android,BB and iPhone?

Tags: android

I have a client who has a requirement for a chatting app. This app should make communication possible on Android and Blackberry.

Wonder if this is technically feasible? If yes then how? Any clue?

Comment: Are you looking for a technique or an App that enables BB, Android and Iphone users to chat?

Comment: Of course it's technically feasible. Look at the dozen or so chat apps in these phones' respective app stores for proof. You'll need to be a great deal more specific and focused with your question.

Comment: @Janusz I want to know if one can develop such an app. Is it possible for a developer?

Comment: @Michael Petrotta Like what else you want to know?

Comment: @Maxood: ask a specific question. You're writing a client-server application. Have you started? Are you stuck somewhere? Is there a particular element that you're not sure can be accomplished? Are you worried about Apple, or RIM, not approving your app for their stores? Worried about server load?  Cross-platform concerns? Try something, and get back to us.

Comment: his question is straight forward. He asked for architectural type of answer.

Comment: @Maxood yes it is possible. Even for a developer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all you need is a chat server and clients on both mobile devices that utilize the server. 
All these frameworks support web services, so its quite easy to create a web-service to handle this on the server for you.

You can probably skip the server and let them talk directly to each other.

Comment: You mean that we need to socket programming here! Just like we do it for a multiplayer games like Tic-Tac-Toe, Chess, etc.

Comment: if you wish, but in this age, thats kinda too low level. Use web services, you can build them using .net or java very easily.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [WhatsApp](http://www.whatsapp.com/)—you can send text, pics and more.

Comment: There are dozen of chat apps, not only WhatsApp which is getting your phone number and phone number of your friends (even your butcher if you have his phone number...)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a technique to build three apps that can chat with each other regardless of phone OS this surely can be done.

You need to look for a chatting standard that is covered with libraries for all the three systems. I would look into Jabber/XMPP. It is the most commonly used open standard for submitting messages and at least for Android there is the [Smack library](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/index.jsp) that will run on Android and give you all the necessary functionality. I don't know 
which libraries can be used on iPhone or BB but there should be something available at least on the iPhone.